# Providing different services in dependent modules

Tags: angular

I have two modules `FirstModule` and `SecondModule`.

Those in general are two separate modules but `SecondModule` imports `FirstModule`.

I have also service `DummyService` that should be different if I use it with `FirstModule` and different if I use it in `SecondModule`.
Problem is that in components from `FirstModule` Angular uses service from `SecondModule`.

Can I make Angular to use services provided in `@NgModule`?

Here is some code:

`FirstModule`:

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule
    ],
    providers: [
        {
            provide: DummyService,
            useClass: DummyFirstService,
        }
    ]
})
export class FirstModule {
}
```

`SecondModule`:

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        FirstModule,
    ],
    providers: [
        {
            provide: DummyService,
            useClass: DummySecondService,
        }
    ]
})
export class SecondModule {
}
```

**Edit:**

I need this for extending component that I build.
Here is component's code from `FirstModule`:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'schemater-input-field',
    template: `
        <ng-container #fieldComponent></ng-container>`,
    providers: [
        {
            provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
            useExisting: forwardRef(() => SchematerInputFieldComponent),
            multi: true
        },
        {
            provide: NG_VALIDATORS,
            useExisting: forwardRef(() => SchematerInputFieldComponent),
            multi: true
        }
    ]
})
export class SchematerInputFieldComponent implements ControlValueAccessor, AfterContentInit, OnInit, OnDestroy {
    protected _value: any;

    protected componentRef: ComponentRef<SchematerInputField>;
    protected _subscriptions: Subscription[] = [];

    @Input() public field: SchematerFieldConfig;
    @Input() protected formControlName: string;
    @Input() protected formGroup: FormGroup;
    @ViewChild('fieldComponent', {read: ViewContainerRef})
    fieldComponentContainer: ViewContainerRef;

    constructor(protected componentResolverService: ComponentResolverService) {
    }

    ngAfterContentInit() {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        if (this.field && !this.field.id && this.formControlName) {
            this.field.id = this.formControlName;
        }

        //get correct component from service/config
        const fieldComponent = this.componentResolverService.createInputComponent(this.field.type); 
        this.componentRef = this.fieldComponentContainer.createComponent(fieldComponent);
        this.componentRef.instance.field = this.field;
        this.componentRef.instance.formGroup = this.formGroup;
        this.componentRef.instance.value = this._value;

        this._subscriptions.push(
            this.componentRef.instance.updateValue.subscribe(e => {
                this.value = e;
            })
        );
    }

    get value(): any {
        return this._value;
    }

    set value(value: any) {
        this._value = value;
        this.propagateChange(this._value);
    }

    writeValue(value: any) {
        if (value !== undefined) {
            this._value = value;
            if (this.componentRef) {
                this.componentRef.instance.value = this._value;
            }
        }
    }

    propagateChange = (_: any) => {
    };

    registerOnChange(fn) {
        this.propagateChange = fn;
    }

    registerOnTouched() {
    }

    validate(c: FormControl) {
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        this.componentRef.destroy();
        this._subscriptions.forEach(subscriber => subscriber.unsubscribe());
    }
}
```

In `SecondModule` I need the same code only with different `constructor` instance.

`export class SchematerSearchFieldComponent extends SchematerInputFieldComponent {}`

Maybe there is other way to extend component's class with different constructor params?

Comment: you want to get difference instance of service in different module ??

Comment: So the problem is solved ?

Comment: @PranayRana yes - how to do that?

Comment: why not have 2 services if they should be different?

Comment: Services are different but I'm building components that component in `SecondModule` extends component from `FirstModule` but with different `service` in constructor: `DummyService`

Comment: That's wrong way. It's impossible to do that. Explaining the situation in details and why exactly you need that (abstract names don't really help) may help to find an appropriate solution.

Comment: I don't know any way to do that, but what you can do is that the service is an "empty box" with functions that create instances of objects, store them in an array, and a getter for each module to retreive the specific object instance it created.

Comment: I've edited to clearify my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want separate instance of service at component level than you need to pass service name in provider list of component.

example :

**component 1**

```
@Component ({
    selector : 'comp1',
    template : `component1`,
    providers : [StateService]
})
```

**component 2**

```
@Component ({
    selector : 'comp2',
    template : `component2`,
    providers : [DummyService]
})
```

Note : as you are referring module this can help, separate instance at component level.

Comment: Great - I need those services in component level so it does resolve my issue.